# Chocolate Feast Program

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve [the Chocolate Feast challenge on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/chocolate-feast#!):

> Little Bob loves chocolate, and he goes to a store with $N in his pocket. The price of each chocolate is $C. The store offers a discount: for every M wrappers he gives to the store, he gets one chocolate for free. How many chocolates does Bob get to eat?
>
> Input Format: 
>   The first line contains the number of test cases, T. 
>   T lines follow, each of which contains three integers, N, C, and M.
>
> Output Format: 
>   Print the total number of chocolates Bob eats.
>
> Constraints:

```
1≤T≤1000 
2≤N≤105 
1≤C≤N 
2≤M≤N
```

> Sample input:

```
3
10 2 5
12 4 4
6 2 2
```

> Sample Output:

```
6
3
5
```

> Explanation 
>   In the first case, he can buy 5 chocolates with $10 and exchange the 5 wrappers to get one more chocolate. Thus, the total number of chocolates is 6.
>
> In the second case, he can buy 3 chocolates for $12. However, it takes 4 wrappers to get one more chocolate. He can't avail the offer and hence the total number of chocolates remains 3.
>
> In the third case, he can buy 3 chocolates for $6. Now he can exchange 2 of the 3 wrappers and get 1 additional piece of chocolate. Now he can use his 1 unused wrapper and the 1 wrapper of the new piece of chocolate to get one more piece of chocolate. So the total is 5.

Here is my attempt at a solution in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int t; //total test cases
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n; //money
        int c; //cost of 1 chocolate
        int m; //no of wrappers to buy a new chocolate
        scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&c,&m);
        int tc=0,nw=0,nc=0,w=0;//tc=totalChocolates  nw=newWrappers nc=newChocolates w=wrappers
        tc=n/c;
        w=tc;
        while(w>=m){
            nc=(w/m);
            tc+=nc;
            w-=m;
            nw=w%m;
            w+=nw;
        }
        printf("%d\n",tc);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my program passes some test cases whereas it fails in some others, but I am not able to find where the error is.
Moreover for some other test the time taken is above 2 secs.

> Test case
>   [Input](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/input05.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1448540250&Signature=g8E2FvOo%2FVvKJOTcsLLiH7WWaEk%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) 
>   [Excepted output](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/output05.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1448540252&Signature=AyTzGkT2SapKgIxgncAY8hn318w%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: Meaningful variable name and some comments would help other people to understand what you're trying to do in your code.

Comment: Check the return value from scanf

Comment: Go to Switzerland for  a chocolate feast

Comment: Please don't change the code once people have supplied answers - it makes the answers invalid and therefore of little use to future readers. (Adding comments is fine, but please don't change the actual code). Please also see the answers below as either of these solves the problem, so you should probably up-vote and/or accept useful answer(s).

Comment: Sorry @PaulR my mistake.
Anyways yours was a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic here is rather muddled:

```
    while(w>=m){
        nc=(w/m);
        tc+=nc;
        w-=m;
        nw=w%m;
        w+=nw;
    }
```

If you change it to this then it passes all the test cases:

```
    while(w>=m){
        nc=(w/m);     // how many additional bars can we buy ?
        tc+=nc;       // accumulate total bars purchased
        w-=(nc*m);    // deduct no of wrappers used to purchase additional bars
        w+=nc;        // accumulate additional wrappers
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This program (before editing) outputs `10` instead of `9` for this input.

```
1
5 1 2
```

Try this in the `while` loop:

- Subtract `m*nc` instead of `m` from `w`
- Add `nc` instead of `nw` to `tc`